# Welcher Satz ist grammatisch richtig? Oder beide sind falsch? "in Relativsatz"

Tags: grammaticality, infinitive, relative-clause

Ich möchte Relativsatz mit dem Wort "Angehörige" benutzen. Und die Bedeutung ist im folgenden Satz:

Der Familienvater ist berechtigt, Unterhalt für Angehörige zu zahlen.

Welcher Satz ist grammatisch richtig? Oder beide sind falsch?

1- Angehörige, für die, der Familienvater berechtigt ist, Unterhalt zu zahlen.

2- Angehörige, für die Unterhalt, der Familienvater berechtigt ist, zu zahlen.

Comment: Weder 1 noch 2 sind vollständige Sätze. Es wird auch nicht klar was ausgesagt werden soll.

Comment: Mich erwischt du nicht!

Beide Sätze sind falsch, weil es kein Recht ist, sondern eine Pflicht.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Das Beispiel enthält eine Infinitivkonstruktion (fett markiert). Ich ersetzte *berechtigt* durch *verpflichtet*, weil das mehr Sinn ergibt.

> 1) Der Familienvater ist verpflichtet, **Unterhalt für Angehörige zu zahlen**.

Möchte man einen Relativsatz formulieren, der sich auf *Angehörige* bezieht, wird diese Infinitivkonstruktion wie folgt aufgespalten: *für die* leitet den Relativsatz ein, aber *Unterhalt zu zahlen* bleibt am Ende des Satzes.

> 1') Angehörige, **für die** der Familienvater verpflichtet ist, **Unterhalt zu zahlen**

Eine etwas weniger natürliche Variante wäre:

> 2) Angehörige, **für die** der Familienvater **Unterhalt zu zahlen** verpflichtet ist

Schon im Ausgangsbeispiel hätte es auch heißen können:

> 2') Der Familienvater ist **Unterhalt für Angehörige zu zahlen** verpflichtet.

Wie natürlich die zweite Variante ist, hängt von dem Verb ab, das die Infinitivkonstruktion einbettet. Bei *versuchen* klingen für mich beide Varianten etwa gleich gut.

> 3) Sie hatte versucht, **ihren Chef von ihrem Standpunkt zu überzeugen**.
>   4) Sie hatte **ihren Chef von ihrem Standpunkt zu überzeugen** versucht.
>
> 3') der Standpunkt, **von dem** sie versucht hatte, **ihren Chef zu überzeugen**
>   4') der Standpunkt, **von dem** sie **ihren Chef zu überzeugen** versucht hatte

Answer (score 4):

> Der Familienvater ist berechtigt, Unterhalt für Angehörige zu zahlen.

Das sollte vermutlich eher lauten

> Der Familienvater ist **verpflichtet**, Unterhalt für Angehörige zu zahlen.

(Das gilt im übrigen auch für alle anderen Erwachsenen. Auch erwachsene Kinder müssen für ihre Eltern Unterhalt bezahlen. Das kommt im Pflegefall regelmäßig vor.)

> Angehörige, für die<s>,</s> der Familienvater verpflichtet ist, Unterhalt zu zahlen<s>.</s>:

Das ist kein vollständiger Satz, da das finite Verb des Hauptsatzes fehlt. Es taugt aber als Überschrift eines Feldes in einem Formular. Das zweite Komma ist jedoch falsch gesetzt, und ans Ende gehört ein Doppelpunkt.

> <s>Angehörige, für die Unterhalt, der Familienvater verpflichtet ist, zu zahlen.</s>

Hier stimmt das Subjekt des Relativsatzes nicht. In Nebensätzen muss das Subjekt direkt der Einleitung des Nebensatzes folgen. *Unterhalt* ist allerdings das Objekt, das gezahlt wird.

Comment: Ich vermute, dass der letzte Satzfetzen lauten sollte: _"Angehörige, für die der Familienvater Unterhalt zu zahlen verpflichtet ist"_.

Comment: Da wird sich die Mutter aber freuen, wenn der Vater von seinem Recht gebrauch macht!

Comment: Vielen Dank für ihre Hilfe! :)